# Tips about designing containers

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

Every time when I'm designing new data structures in C++, I have some troubles with pointers, references, constness, etc. Can somebody please recommend me good books with good tips about designing containers?

P.S book of John Meyers, is that good choice?

Comment: What kind of container are you thinking of designing? What do you hope to accomplish by doing so? The standard library already provides several useful ones, which pretty much cover the bases of what we normally think of as a "container" in computer science.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I want to understandd good principles, and how does it work, that's why I'm asking... if You want to be good programmer, You must understand how stuff is working, am I wrong?

Comment: Re-implementing things is not necessarily the best way to understand them. Better to read detailed descriptions of how the standard implementations typically work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed description of how the STL is implemented in "The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference" by Nicolai M. Josuttis.

Meyer's Effective STL is less comprehensive but does have a section on containers.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Meyers' Effective C++ is a pretty good resource for general C++ wizardry and it does have a great discussion of class design, but I honestly think that his "More Effective C++" is a bit more appropriate to what you're talking about.  It talks a lot about class design concepts like reference counting, copy-on-write, etc.  It might be a bit advanced for what you're looking for, but it's perhaps the best intro to advanced class design out there.

I also think that Herb Sutter's "Exceptional C++" might be good.  I know that it has a pretty good discussion about designing the string class, and that single example is so useful that I would recommend it above everything else.  That discussion [is also available online](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm), if you find that useful.

Both of those discussions are more about the mechanics of designing a good abstraction around a data structure, but they don't talk much about data structures in general.  There are a lot of fascinating data structures out there, and it's probably a good idea to see some of them in action before trying to implement your own.  I'm personally of the school of thought that you can learn a lot about class design by taking known data structures and coding them up, though I concede that this might not be the optimal way of learning how to code.  If you're interested in seeing some fun data structures (like the binary heap, red-black tree, binomial heap, B tree, disjoint-set forest, and Fibonacci heap), consider picking up a copy of "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition" by Cormen, Leisserson, Rivest, and Stein.  It's widely considered one of the best texts on algorithms, and has enough pseudocode that if you wanted to write up a good data structure, you could almost certainly find enough hints here.  These structures, combined with the above books, should have all sorts of info.  It's a lot of reading, granted, but you'll be well on your way toward data structure guruship if you can make it through them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, what about STL of Meyers, is it good book?